# Таймер не запускается по новой,а уходит в минус

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

при нажатии на кнопку "новая игра" таймер доходит до нуля и останавливается игра,
при повторном нажатии на кнопку "новая игра" таймер не обнуляется,а начинает идти в минус (-10,-11 и тд).
Как сделать,чтобы таймер обнулялся при каждом нажатии "новая игра"?

Вот фрагменты программы,связанные с таймером:

```
    public void BtnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Enabled = true; 
        timer1.Start();     
        init();
        btnGuess.Enabled = true;
    }
    int tic = 50;



    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //timer1 = new Timer();
        string t = Convert.ToString(tic);
        label2.Text = "До конца осталось " + t + " секунд(ы)";
        tic--;
        if (tic == 0)
            if (tic == 0)
            {
                label3.Text = " Время вышло!";
                timer1.Stop();                   

                    btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                label4.Text = "Извините,вы проиграли";

            }
```

[image: таймер уходит в минус]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы заходите в блок `if(tik == 0)`, сразу обнуляйте(`tik = 50`) tik. В вашем коде я этого маневра не заметил.

Comment: как это сделать,не подскажите?

Comment: Что вы конкретно не поняли из того, что я написал?

Comment: спасибо большое,получилось,можете добавить,Как ответ

Comment: Что добавить? Вы можете его принять, если что